# Find the Least Integer $k$ such that $B^k=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

9>If $A$ and $B$ are two non-singular matrices such that $B\ne I$, $A^6=I$ and $$AB^2=BA,$$ then what is the  least positive integer $k$ such that $B^k=I$?

My Try: Given $$AB^2=BA$$ which we can write as
$$ABB=BA$$ Post Multiply with $A$ we get

$$ABBA=BA^2$$ i.e., $$ABAB^2=BA^2$$ i.e.,

$$A^2B^4=BA^2$$ Continuing we get

$$A^3B^8=BA^3$$

$$A^4B^{16}=BA^4$$

$$A^5B^{32}=BA^5$$ and finally

$$A^6B^{64}=BA^6$$ and since $A^6=I$ we have

$$B^{64}=B$$ i.e,

$$B^{63}=I$$ so $k$ is 63.

Can i have any better approach?

Comment: This looks like a very good approach, and it looks like your answer is correct

Comment: Actually, what you proved here is that $k\leq 63$. I think, you should prove the converse to conclude.

Comment: Actually, what you proved here is that k divides 63. You should prove a kind of converse to conclude.

Answer (score 3):

A slightly different way to write what you've written: rewrite the first equality as
$$
B^2 = A^{-1}BA
$$
from there, we have
$$
B^{2^2}=(B^2)^2 = (A^{-1}BA)^2 = A^{-1}B^2A = A^{-1}(A^{-1}BA)A = A^{-2}BA^2
$$
by these steps (which could be used in an inductive proof), we have
$$
B^{2^k}=A^{-k}BA^k
$$
so, we have $B^{64} = B$.

Comment: Very nice but how can we prove that $63$ is the Least?

Comment: There could exist specific matrices where 63 isn't the least. For example, if $A=I$, then we have $B^2 = B$ (IE the projection matrices).

Comment: @CalvinLin But then isn't $B$ singular? So we cannot have $A=I.$

Comment: Ah oops, that example doesn't work. Here's another. If $A^3 = I$, then the same argument would say that the "least" is 7 in that specific case (assuming a non-singular $B$ exists).

Comment: Of course, the likely interpretation is that we can find an $A, B$ such that $B^{63} = I$ is the least solution. I'm guessing that there's some nice construction, but am too tired to work it out.