# How $k=63$ is Least?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I was going through a Problem in an existing Thread:
[Find the Least Integer $k$ such that $B^k=I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1160147/find-the-least-integer-k-such-that-bk-i)

In the Approach given by OP and Omno we get:
$$B^{63}=I$$

But How can we Justify that $63$ is Least?

My try:

I tried to check all powers of $B$ till $62$

We have $B \ne I$

Let $B^2=I$ Then
$AB^2=BA$ $\implies$ $A=BA$ $\implies$ $B=I$ a Contradiction , Hence
$$B^2\ne I$$

Also:

$$B^{63}=I$$
$$B^{62}=B^{-1}\ne I$$
$\implies$
$$B^{31}\ne I$$

So i could easily prove that

$B,B^2,B^{31}, B^{62}\ne I$

But now how to prove other powers of $B$ less than $63$ arealso not $I$?

Comment: Given $B\ne I$ and $B$ is invertible, it suffices to show that $B^{21}\ne I$ and $B^9\ne I$

Comment: Your objection is valid. The reason why checking those numbers is sufficient, is that if $A^n = I, A^m = I$, then we can conclude that $A^{\gcd(n,m)}=I$. Thus, we only need to check the factors of $n$.In fact, a stronger statement is that we only need to check $n/p_i$, where $p_i$ are the primes that divide $n$.

Comment: What about other even powers of $B$

Comment: Calvin Lin showed that $k$ cannot be even, because $\gcd(2n,63)<2n.$ But for example, if $B^4=I$ then $I=(B^4)^{16} = B^{64} = B,$ contradiction. If $B^6=I$ then $I=(B^6)^{11} = B^{66} = B^3,$ so $k\neq 6$, but then also $I=(B^3)^3=B^9$, so if you can prove $B^9\neq I$ you can prove $B^3\neq I.$

Comment: Perfectly Clear now

Answer (score 3):

The least $k$ can be smaller than $63$. E.g. when
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&I_3\\ I_3&0},
\ B=\pmatrix{C&0\\ 0&C^2},
\ C=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\ 0&0&1\\ 1&0&0},
$$
we have $A^2=A^6=I$ and $AB^2=\pmatrix{0&C\\ C^2&0}=BA$ but $B^3=I\ne B$.

(In the above counterexample, $A$ is annihilated by $x^2-1$. Perhaps the least $k$ is $63$ when the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $x^6-1$, but I don't know whether this hypothesis is true or not.)